# jQuery - addClass not adding class to html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to add CSS class to `<li>` element, when I click on the button but addClass not working.

Here is my JS:

```
$('.test').click(function(event) {
    var centrum1 = $('.p17');
    $('section.bok-map').find( centrum1 ).addClass('active-region');
});
```

And this how is looking HTML code:
[image]

Where is the problem? find() returns true.
Here is demo: http://demo.vrs-factory.pl/mapDemo/

Comment: `.find()` should return `element` wrapped with `jQ`

Comment: @Vertisan it works for me. Have you defined .active-region somewhere in the css? if i set it to `.active-region{color:red}` it works

Comment: Yes, when I add this class manualy in debbuger, so it's working but only this function won't add class

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Sure, here you are: http://demo.vrs-factory.pl/mapDemo/

Comment: Length of `selector` is `0`

Comment: @RayonDabre see my answer below for the reasons the length of `selector` is 0

Comment: @Vertisan the below code should get you started as it is now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a couple of errors, as you were not selecting the correct element, hence the length of the `selector` was 0.

Firstly, the class is called `pl7` not `p17` and secondly, when using `removeClass` you don't put the `.` before the name of the class. As you are using `removeClass` it is understood that you want to target a class, hence not requiring you to specify this by adding the dot.

```
 <script>
      var centrum1 = $('.pl7');

      $('.test').click(function(event) {            
          $('section.bok-map').find( centrum1 ).removeClass('pl7');
      });

 </script>
```

Also, it may be worth noting that since you are only referencing`$(.pl7)` once you do not necessarily have to assign it to a variable. You could also write it as below. It is up to you.

```
  $('.test').click(function(event) {            
       $('section.bok-map').find('.pl7').removeClass('pl7');
  });
```

Comment: @RayonDabre I was just fixing his code as he had it.

Comment: I get caching elements that are selected multiple times but is it more efficient to cache elements that are selected only once?